# Should I call deliver method when sending mail using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, sidekiq

In rails guide, I see the way to deliver email is calling like this:

```
UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver
```

But in our codebase, I see code like this using sidekiq:

```
UserMailer.delay.welcome(@user)
```

And likely it works. I am wondering, should I call `deliver` to make the action happen or sidekiq does some magic here?

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions) documentation, I think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in `Sidekiq`'s sources ([click here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/extensions/action_mailer.rb#L20)) it calls `deliver` for you. Thats why you don't need to call it when you delay email.